# Vue Quasar modal put in component in message

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I have a q-btn. When i click on it, it will pop up a modal.

```
<q-btn 
    @click="handler(userA)" 
    round color="primary" 
    icon="perm_identity"/>
```

This handler below is in my data return object.

```
handler: (userA) => {
            console.log(`handler: ${userA}`)
            this.$q.dialog({
              title: 'Alert',
              message: '{{<buyer-info></buyer-info>}}'
            }).catch(() => {})
          }
```

Currently, the message shown is exactly `{{<buyer-info></buyer-info>}}.` I have registered a

```
components: { 'buyer-info': BuyerInfo },
```

my BuyerInfo component has the `<template><h1>hi</hi></template>` but this is not getting rendered.

How can i get this to render on the modal message?

Comment: Because q-dialog is a component's wrapper, which changes to normal HTML tags during build operation. So, you can't use vue's components in dynamic style. You should place dialog component directly in your app as a new separate component.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using custom Dialog.

```
<q-dialog
        v-model="customDialogModel"
        stack-buttons
        prevent-close
        @ok="onOk"
        @cancel="onCancel"
      >
        <span slot="title">Alert</span>
        <span slot="message"><buyer-info></buyer-info></span>
      </q-dialog>


methods: {
    onOk(){
      alert("hi")
    },
    onCancel(){
        alert("cancle")
    },
    handler(){
        this.customDialogModel=true
    }
  },
```